# Pass rendered string into Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, templates, dynamic, angularjs-directive, attributes

I am trying to make an angular directive that renders dynamic content urls based on an attribute placed on the directive. Example:

Directive:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myContent', directive);

function directive() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return attrs.contentUrl;
        }
    };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div my-content content-url="url/to/my-content.html"></div>
```

However what I would like is for the `content-url` attribute to be populated by a string from the controller.  So let's say the controller is using the "controllerAs" syntax with the name "home", I would like the html to read:

```
<div my-content content-url="{{home.myContent.url}}"></div>
```

However within the directive's templateUrl function, the `contentUrl` attribute is being sent literally as "{{home.myContent.url}}".  How can I get this value to evaluate before running the templateUrl function?  Or, is there a better way to have simple, dynamic content available from a directive?

Comment: Should be possible by adding`scope: { conentUrl: '=' } ` to your directive function, and leave out the curly brackets when using the it in your html. Then you need to $watch the value of $scope.contentUrl in the directive. Alternatively you should also be able to use $attr.$observe in link function of the directive, though I don't have much experience with that. Google is you friend :-)

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to recreate what angular already does natively with ng-include. Unless you're trying to recreate it for learning purposes, I'd just use ng-include. Otherwise, might not be a bad idea to check out the source code to see how they do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is provided by @crhistian-ramirez:

Just use ng-include

```
<div ng-include="vm.myContent.url"></div>
```